# pointer to strings

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

The following two code snippets compiles without any errors/warnings but while running it crashes. Kindly enlighten me.

Program 1

```
 int main( )
{
   char *p= "Hello" ;

   *p = 'B' ;
    printf("\n%s",p);

   return 0;
}
```

Program 2

```
int main( )
{
   char *p= "Hello" ;
   Char *q="mug"
   *q = *p ;
    printf("\n%s",q);

   return 0;
}
```

For program 2 i expected output to be 'Hug'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you do:

```
char *p= "Hello";
```

You are defining a string literal.  String literals are constant data and as you've found out, modifying them results in undefined behavior (often a crash).  It should be declared as:

```
const char *p = "Hello";
```

So the compiler will throw an error if you try to modify it.

Now if you define it instead as:

```
char p[] = "Hello";
```

The memory is then allocated on the stack and you can modify it.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char p[] = "Hello" ;

    *p = 'B' ;
    printf("\n%s",p);

    return 0;
}
```

Outputs `Bello`

For program 2, note only `q` needs to be on the stack.  `p` can remain a `const` pointer to a string literal, since you're only reading from it.

```
int main( )
{
    const char *p = "Hello" ;
    char q[] = "mug";
    *q = *p ;
    printf("\n%s",q);

    return 0;
}
```

Outputs `Hug`

Answer (score 0):

In both samples you are modifying string literals, which yields undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

What you should write is:

```
char p[] = "Hello";
```

The form above (char p [] = "Hello") tells the compiler, "I've got an array of values coming up, please allocate as much space as is needed for them." It also works with ints, for example:

```
int i [] = { 1, 2, 5, 100, 50000 };
```

You'll end up with i being a pointer to an array of 5 values.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that shortly after I posted it and removed it. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a static string in the form of  char *p = "test" the contents of the pointer cannot be changed. In your case trying to modify the contents of the pointer yields to the error that you are observing.

Answer (score 0):

I changed program 2 to not use string literals. It shows "Hug" as you expected.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( )
{
   char p[10];
   char q[10];
   strcpy(p,"Hello");
   strcpy(q,"mug");
   *q = *p ;
   printf("\n%s",q);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are already 4 answers to why the code fails. This answer explains how to do it right.

Answer (score 0):

The strings "Hello" and "mug" are stored in read-only memory and you are trying to write there.

```
$ gcc -S a.c
$ cat a.s
    .file   "a.c"
    .section        .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "Hello"
.LC1:
```

Note that the section is "rodata" (read-only data).

Comment: Atom does it mean the literal is stored in "Code/text segment". That is why it becomes RO?

Comment: The literal is stored in section ".rodata", which contains data (not code), and the flags in the ELF executable are saying that the section is read-only. There are also other sections such as ".text" and ".data". You can use "readelf --sections executable_file" to print all the sections, the "Flg" column specifies the section's access rights.